# Amazon IOS SDK: compiler warnings - ARC issue?

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, amazon-web-services, automatic-ref-counting

I have used Amazon's iOS SDK successfully to up- and download files from S3.  Since upgrading to Xcode 4.2, Amazon SDK 1.0.4 and building apps using ARC (again successfully) I get 49 warning messages whenever I compile.

These include:
S3ListPartsResult.h: 
- Lexical or Preprocessor Issue
-- Extra tokens at end of #import directive

AmazonServiceResponse.h
- Semantic Issue
-- No assign, retain or copy attribute

Any one have any idea what is causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try compile the SDK into a  static library. You can choose the non-arc mode for the library. Then compile it and drag the library to your framework folder. That solved my issue.